# updating all array elements of a field of a meteor collection

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor

I have updated my Meteor.users() collection to include a 'profile' subdoc and inside profile I have an array of objects called 'notifications'. The object structure for notifications looks like this:

```
           'profile.notifications': {
            prompt: prompt,
            message: message,
            hasBeenRead: false,
            timestamp: Messages.find({}, {sort: {"ts": 1}, limit: 0}).fetch().pop().ts,
           }
```

Is there a way, using one of Mongo's methods, to change `hasBeenRead` to true for all of the objects within the array? I can change just one element using array indexes (the code below), but I can't use this approach to change all of them at once.

```
    Meteor.users.update({
       _id:  Meteor.userId() 
     }, {
        'profile.notifications.0.hasBeenRead': true //only changes first elem
        }
     })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to update all elements of an array through mongo directly. You can either send multiple updates to mongo or extract the *notifications* array, update all the elements, then update the document in one go.

```
var notifications = Meteor.user().profile.notifications;
notifications.forEach(function(e,i,a){a[i].hasBeenRead=true});
Meteor.users.update({ _id: Meteor.userId() },
  { $set: { 'profile.notifications': notifications }});
```